# creating sqlite databse in android( SQLiteOpenHelper Class OR openOrCreateDatabase method?)

Tags: android, sqlite

Are there two different ways of creating SQLite databases in Android?
What is the difference between the onCreate method of SQLiteOpenHelper Class and the openOrCreateDatabase method? Both of them make a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SqliteOpenHelper` is a class that manages some of the easily misunderstood parts of database handling such as creation, upgrading and version management.

There is no rule that says you must use it and you are more than welcome to use the direct database creating methods if you so wish but using `SqliteOpenHelper`does simplify things greatly.

If you check the source code, you will see that `SqliteOpenHelper` actually uses 'openOrCreateDatabase' internally anyway.

Comment: do u mean i can use both way to create sqlite DataBase( openOrCreatDatabase and SqliteOpenHelper class)?

Comment: You can use either one. `SqliteOpenHelper` is easiest if you do not want to handle the version management etc yourself but `openOrCreateDatabase` gives you more control over the process.